# Check if 5 out of 6 Columns meets criteria

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I have a SQL Report that has the following columns:

| Name | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 | Product 4 | Product 5 | Product 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SM1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| SM2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| SM3 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| SM4 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

Every product has a goal, so:

- Product 1: 2
- Product 2: 2
- Product 3: 2
- Product 4: 1
- Product 5: 1
- Product 6: 1

I need to check if the Name has met the goal in **at least 5 out of 6 products**.

The columns for the products were created with a `COUNT(CASE WHEN...)`.

My ideal output would be to add a column after the product 6, like that:

| Name | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 | Product 4 | Product 5 | Product 6 | Qualifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SM1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 | Yes |
| SM2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 0 | No |
| SM3 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | Yes |
| SM4 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 | No |

- SM1 and SM3 didn't meet the goal on Product 2, but it was met on the other 5 products, so it's a yes.
- SM2 didn't meet the goal on Products 1, 3 and 6, so it's a no.
- SM4 didn't meet the goal on Products 1, 2, and 6, so it's a no.

The only thing I could think to solve this problem was to create a combination of the products, but that would be extensive (and probably unnecessary).

Another thing I tried to figure out was to add a column that counts how many columns had the goal met, (i.e., SM1 = 5, SM2 = 3, SM3 = 3, SM4 = 5), and from that column, create the Qualifier one that checks if the previous column is 5 or over. But I couldn't figure out a way to do that yet, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about is whether at least 5 products met the goals..just sum them up conditionally

```
select *,
    iff(iff(p1>=2,1,0)+
        iff(p2>=2,1,0)+
        iff(p3>=2,1,0)+
        iff(p4>=1,1,0)+
        iff(p5>=1,1,0)+
        iff(p6>=1,1,0) >=5,'Yes','No')
from t;
```